# Zend Framework 3 Hydrator

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-hydrator

I have this code:

```
        $settingsModel = new Settings();
        $hydrator = new ReflectionHydrator();
        $incomingData = array('[meta_title]' => 'CMS');
        $datas = $hydrator->hydrate($incomingData, $settingsModel);
```

When i print $datas i get empty object

```
Admin\Model\Settings Object
(
)
```

On top my Controller i have:

```
use Zend\Hydrator;
use ReflectionClass;
use Zend\Hydrator\Reflection as ReflectionHydrator;
```

Any advice?

Comment: If you inspect the object (`$datas`) with xdebug, what do you see?

Comment: Using the reflection hydrator any data key matching an existing property will be hydrated. Does your `Settings` object actually have an existing `meta_title` property?

Comment: Right now is working good